# JAVA - How do I write variables to a text file with a specific style?

Tags: java, text-files

```
            String cDate = getDate();
            String cClientName = getClientName();
            String cRN = getRN();
            int cPackage = getPackage();
            int cDB = getDB(cPackage);                
            int cPeriod = getPeriod(cRN);
            boolean cIC = getIC();
            double mCharge = getMCharge(cPackage, cDB, cPeriod, cRN, cIC);
            saveContract(cDate, cClientName, cRN, cPackage, cDB, cPeriod, cIC, mCharge);
```

I have these variables and want to be able to save these variables to a text file as such:

15-Sep-2015_TAB_ Client name_TAB_Reference number_TAB_Package

My question is: How do I write these variables to a text file (which I want to read from the file later) using a tab to seperate each variable?

Comment: Simply use `"\t"`?

Comment: try using a varargs in the method saveContract(String... args). Then loop through the arguments and add deleimiter after adding the arg in the file.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using the varargs parameter. This would give output for mergeParams("test1", "test2", "test3"); as "test1  test2   test3" values separated by "\t" ie tabs

```
  private static void mergeParams(String... params) {

    for(int i = 0; i < params.length; i++) {
        System.out.print(params[i]+"\t");
    }
  }
```